# mysql jump first row while insert data

Tags: php, mysql, database, count, row

can some kindheart give me a short explanation about this?

```
<?php

$selection = query("SELECT * FROM rows_test"); 
/* query() is an abbreviation of mysqli_query();*/

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($selection);

$row_id = '';

$row_string = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

for($row_id=1; $row_id<=$num_rows; $row_id++){

    $row_string = 'ROW-' . date('Y') . '-' .$row_id;

}


$sql  = "INSERT INTO rows_test (row_id, row_string) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ('{$row_id}','{$row_string}')";

$result = query($sql);
confirm_query($result); /*Test if there is a result*/


}


?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Button" />
</form>
```

With this code php insert in the table the first row_string empty and the row_id =1 (i get that this is because i assign the value for row_id in the for loop)..
after the first then it works fine as i expect so from the table id=2 it start what i want. 
but i need that the row_id is the same as the table id(that is of course auto increment).

By the way i know there's a way to do without row_id but i'm just testing some other ways to do things.

Comment: need more details

Comment: You are overwriting `$row_string` in your `for` loop, so only the last assigned value will “survive” after the loop ... you probably want to make the INSERT inside the loop as well …?

Comment: @Rajveergangwar basically i want that the row_string increment the value given by the row_id as the same as the autoincremented id in the table. but this start from the second row and not if the table is empty.

Comment: if the `$num_rows` is 4 you want the `$row_id` to be 3?

Comment: @ArunpandianM no i want to be the same.

Comment: then there is no need for for loop i

Comment: try my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe my lack in english make me goofy to be understandable, but this is what i was looking for. this works fine for what i was asking. of course is not very clean, but as i said i was testing something different. thanks for your answers.

```
<?php

$result = query("SELECT * FROM rows_test");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$row_string = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $num_rows == 0){

    $row_id = 1;
    $row_string = 'ORD-' . date('Y') . '-' . 1;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO rows_test (row_id, row_transaction_id) VALUES ('{$row_id}','{$row_string}')";

    $result = query($sql);
    confirm_query($result);


}elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && $num_rows !== 0){

    for($row_id=1; $row_id<=$num_rows; $row_id++){



    }

    $row_string = 'ORD-' . date('Y') . '-' .$row_id;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO rows_test (row_id, row_string) VALUES ('{$row_id}','{$row_string}')";

    $result = query($sql);
    confirm_query($result);


    }


?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
for($row_id=0; $row_id<$num_rows; $row_id++){
```

Comment: yeah tried but it just give me the row_id=0 in the table my problem is with the empty row_string.

Comment: keep $i=1; and place "}" after the your query

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the same data to be inserted in the rows_test as per the count of rows_test

change your rows_test insert query as listed below :

```
$selection = query("SELECT * FROM rows_test"); 
/* query() is an abbreviation of mysqli_query();*/

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($selection);

$sql  = "INSERT INTO rows_test (row_id, row_string) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ('{$num_rows}',date('Y'))";
```

Comment: sorry not what i was looking for.. i was look for insert a string concatenation in the table where row_id is exactly the same of the id of the row that auto increment its self.. my problem was not in the row_id, was to attach the proper row_id to the row_string... but no worry i found out how to do.